# When using Metarig, render result looks swollen

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: looks weird when rendered]

Hello,

I'm trying to use Metarig, which has worked quite well so far.
But in render preview and rendering, the face looks swollen.

I render with Cycles and Nvidia Optix.
If I set the render device to None or HIP, the effect is less visible but still there. With Optix and CUDA, the face looks like a boxer's.
You can also see this clearly on the outliner in the left picture.

Anyone know what could be causing this?
Greetings

Answer (score 2):

[image]

OK, found the solution.

the problem was that the image-texture-node for the displacement map was set to non-color and should obviously be set to sRGB instead.